# By Default, What Is A JavaScript Variables's Boolean Value?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I am writing a script the utilizes a switch statement. When I declare the variables, they have a default boolean value of true, correct? Well, not so much when being utilized in a switch statement.

**Here is the JavaScript I have:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IDLqd/

Basically, what I am trying to do is ask the user what type of list-style they prefer based upon that data that is entered into a window.prompt() method. If they enter in a 1, 2, or 3, they will get a list based upon the directions in the prompt. But, if they do not enter in a valid integer, the variable validInput is set with a boolean value of false.

From here, an if statement is ran to check whether the validInput variable has a boolean value of true, if it does, then it outputs the values of the many variables to the screen, if not, it outputs text saying "Invalid Choice".

Why is it that the code will recognize validInput as only having a value of false in the if statement? When it is only assigned the value of false if a different value is entered into the prompt window? To get this program to run properly I have to explicitly define the validInput value as true in each switch case.

Why is this? Can someone explain, please?

Thank you!
Aaron

Comment: A declared but unset variable defaults to `undefined`, which is "falsey", i.e. `undefined == false`, `undefined != true`, but is not actually false, i.e. `undefined !== false`, `undefined !== true`.

Comment: Isnt that because in your case the execution will go to the default and set validinput as false as it is not initialized beforehand?

Comment: @Dave: I get what you are saying, so in a sense, it could be considered null, and null is considered "falsey". What's the difference between undefined and null? Is it always a good practice to always define variables before being used in statements such as the one I have?

Comment: Incidentally, you are using commas and multiple `var`s in your declarations; pick one style or the other, you can't use both simultaneously.

Comment: `undefined == null` but `undefined !== null`. Undefined means literally that; it is not defined to be anything. Whereas null is a sort of blank object (which makes more sense if you have a C or Java background). In JavaScript the distinction isn't really necessary, but can be useful for example when checking which parameters were sent to a function. Just remember that `undefined`, `null`, `false`, `0` and `''` are all "falsey" (as well as a bunch of strings like `'0'`), but they are all different.

Comment: And no, you don't *need* to explicitly set all variables to something. If you're happy with the default `undefined` (which is sometimes OK), just the `var a;` statement is enough. Just remember that it's really more like `var a = undefined;`

Comment: @Dave: Thank you so much for the help and explanation! I understand what you are saying and now know something new about Javascript! :)

Comment: @Dave: `''` is the only falsy string. `'0'` is truthy. This isn't PHP. The only falsy value missing in your list is `NaN`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript is a dynamic language and **there is nothing like a default boolean value**.

When you define a variable without a value it's default value is always `undefined`:

```
var variable; // variable is undefined
```

So **you have to set the value**:

```
var variable = true;
// or
var variable = false;
```

If you want to toggle this boolean value, you can do the following:

```
variable = !variable;
```

Comment: Thank you for this, and I definitely understand what you are saying, but I do not understand your last line there, the variable != variable. Why would you toggle the value as such? As opposed to just defining it? Couldn't that create some sort of never ending error?

Comment: @AaronBrewer This was only a example for changing the boolean value. This can be done anywhere in your application, e.g. changing the state of some flag.

Comment: I think you meant to write `variable = !variable;`

Answer (score 2):

You are checking if the input is valid with

```
if (validInput == true) {
  // Your code
}
```

The more common way of doing this would be

```
if (validInput) {
  // Your code
}
```

What's the difference between these two?

The first checks if `validInput` is equal to `true` - nothing else will do (well, pretty much nothing else - you're using `==` rather than `===`, which can sometimes have surprising results because of javascript's type conversion algorithm, but that's another question altogether).

To understand the second, you need to understand javascript's concept of "truthiness". If you put a value into the condition of an if statement, then javascript decides is it's "truth-y" or "false-y", and acts accordingly.

`true` is truthy, as is any non-zero number, any non-empty string, and any object. Other things are falsey, including `false`, `0`, `""`, `null` and `undefined`.

The last of these is probably the most relevant to you, as variables are `undefined` until you set them to something.

Comment: Thank you so much for this James_pic! I appreciate the answer! :)

Comment: Just for the sake of giving an example of the insanity of type conversion: If `validInput` happens to be a string then `validInput == true` is only true if `validInput === '1'` while `validInput` is truthy as long as `validInput !== ''`.